# Picture with arrows and circles

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I want to create a picture looking like the following[image]

[Here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/labeled-chain/) is a link to create the diagram, but without the circles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The figure under your link looks very different from your screenshot. But as you are referring to it, I use it to show how one can draw dashed ellipses around two nodes.

```
% TikZ chains with labeled edges
% Author: Stefan Kottwitz , http://texblog.net
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,matrix,positioning,scopes,calc,fit,shapes.geometric}
%
\makeatletter
\tikzset{join/.code=\tikzset{after node path={%
\ifx\tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty\else(\tikzchainprevious)%
edge[every join]#1(\tikzchaincurrent)\fi}}}
\makeatother
%
\tikzset{>=stealth',every on chain/.append style={join},
         every join/.style={->}}
\tikzset{labeled/.style={execute at begin node=$\scriptstyle,
   execute at end node=$}}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em, column sep=3em]
    { 0 & A  & B  & C  & 0 \\
      0 & A' & B' & C' & 0 \\ };
  { [start chain] \chainin (m-1-1);
    \chainin (m-1-2);
    { [start branch=A] \chainin (m-2-2)
        [join={node[right,labeled] {\eta_1}}];}
    \chainin (m-1-3) [join={node[above,labeled] {\varphi}}];
    { [start branch=B] \chainin (m-2-3)
        [join={node[right,labeled] {\eta_2}}];}
    \chainin (m-1-4) [join={node[above,labeled] {\psi}}];
    { [start branch=C] \chainin (m-2-4)
        [join={node[right,labeled] {\eta_3}}];}
    \chainin (m-1-5); }
  { [start chain] \chainin (m-2-1);
    \chainin (m-2-2);
    \chainin (m-2-3) [join={node[above,labeled] {\varphi'}}];
    \chainin (m-2-4) [join={node[above,labeled] {\psi'}}];
    \chainin (m-2-5); }
\path let \p1=(m-1-1), \p2=(m-2-2), \n1={atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)} in
node[draw,dashed,ellipse,inner sep=0pt,rotate fit=\n1,fit=(m-1-1) (m-2-2)]{}; %added    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to draw something like your figure, I would actually not use chains since the styles of your arrows vary. To draw arrows between the ellipses (or between an ellipse and another node), just give them a name. I draw the upper half of your figure, the rest is only repetition.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,matrix,calc,fit,shapes.geometric}

\newcommand{\DrawEllipse}[3][]{
\path let \p1=#2, \p2=#3, \n1={atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)} in
node[draw,ellipse,inner sep=0pt,rotate fit=\n1,fit=#2 #3,#1]{};}

%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, row sep=3em, column sep=3em]
    { LEM & LPO  & MP  & WMP   \\
      WLEM & WLPO &  &   \\
      & WKL & & \\
       &|[label={[xshift=-1cm,name=lab,above left,font=\tiny]AC}]| LLPQ & MP\textsuperscript{V} & \\};
\draw[double,-latex] (m-1-1) -- (m-1-2);
\draw[double,-latex] (m-1-2) -- (m-1-3);
\draw[very thick,-latex] (m-1-3) -- (m-1-4);
%
\draw[double,-latex] (m-1-1) -- (m-2-1);
\draw[very thick,-latex] ([xshift=-1mm]m-1-2.south) -- ([xshift=-1mm]m-2-2.north);
\draw[double,-latex] ([xshift=1mm]m-1-2.south) -- ([xshift=1mm]m-2-2.north);
\draw[very thick,-latex] ([xshift=-1mm]m-2-2.south) -- ([xshift=-1mm]m-3-2.north);
\draw[double,-latex] ([xshift=1mm]m-2-2.south) -- ([xshift=1mm]m-3-2.north);
\draw[very thick,-latex] (m-1-3) -- (m-4-3);
\draw[very thick,-latex] (m-3-2) -- (m-4-2);
\DrawEllipse[dashed,name=el1]{(m-2-2)}{(m-1-3)}
\DrawEllipse[dashed,name=el2]{(m-4-3)}{(m-1-4)}
\DrawEllipse[dashed,name=el3]{(m-4-2)}{(lab)}
\draw[<->] (el1.south east) -- (el2.30);
\draw[<->] (el3.-60) -- (m-3-2);
\draw[double,-latex] (el3.west |- m-4-2) -- (el2.west |- m-4-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you also know how to get a design similar to the screenshot? And how do I get arrows pointing from the ellipses to one of the nodes?

Comment: @Diamir I added something that should allow you to reproduce the figure.